# "Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Management Console - External User Management"

Tags: jboss, ldap, external, roles, access-control

How can i assign external ldap users to specific application roles.

There is a section names "Access Control" in management console, and a users section under "Access Control" . My external users not showing here.

Moreover,
In Business-Central.war application setting, there is users seciton. But my ldap users ont showing there too. I wanna assign existing ldap users to business-central application roles manually.   Because of this, i sohuld see external ldap users in this section.
In short can i assign external ldap users to application specific roles manually without add users manually

i want to assign external ldap users to specific application roles manually.